# View with BottomSheetBehaviour is always visible but state is collapsed

Tags: android, fragment, bottom-sheet

I try to add a View with BottomSheetBehaviour to my Fragment. Somehow the view gets displayed but  the state BottomSheetBehaviour is collapsed.

I try to set the state with `setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)` but the action has no effect: the state is still `STATE_COLLAPSED`.

Can someone please tell me why the setState() method has no effect?

```
// called in onViewCreated in my Fragement

private void initLayerButton(View view) {
    View bottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet1);
    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

    layerButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.layerButton);
    layerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() != 
BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {

mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                Log.d(TAG, "expanded");
            }
            else {

mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                Log.d(TAG, "collapsed");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The layout of my Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- some layouts of the view -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="dfsd"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="dsfa"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

To receive callbacks of state changes, you can add a **BottomSheetCallback**

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetCallback() {  
    @Override  
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {  

      // React to state change  

      if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
      //STATE_COLLAPSED
      }else{
      //STATE_EXPANDED;
      }

    }  
      @Override  
      public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {  
       // React to dragging events  
   }  
 });
```

Comment: The problem is that the state  does not change: he is always collapsed. So onStateChanged does not do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to make the bottomsheetbehaviour to set Expand always?

Comment: Thanks for the your question: It should be collapsed when after the view is created. After onButtonClicked ist should expand. Also: I just realised that the the state is 'STATE_SETTLING' and not 'STATE_EXPANDED' as I mistakingly said. With the next button click it should collapse.